# Who should star in the Dark Tower movies?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Rumors say either Javier Bardem or Russell Crowe will star as Roland.  Who would be your choice?  And how about the other characters, Eddie, Susannah, Jake, Cutbert, Susan Delgado...

Comment: We finally have some answers as to who *will* star in the movie:  Idris Elba as Roland, and Matthew McConnaughey as the Man in Black are officially confirmed.  Abby Lee is rumored to be playing a Can-Toi named Tirana.  And a couple of years back, Aaron Paul (from *Breaking Bad*) was in talks to play Eddie.

Answer (score 2):

Adrien Brody would make a good Roland!  Roland can't be some pretty actor.